# [ChartJs]How can I modify the height of the chart instead of changing it through canvas

Tags: chart.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myov6.png)
my options like this

datalabels: {
align: "end",
offset: 40,
},

Because I set the offset, the content on it exceeded the canvas and was hidden.
The same problem occurs in the line chart when I display data at the top ,like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUjyM.png)

I guess it's because the content exceeds the height of the canvas. I want to know if I can reduce the width and height of the chart without changing the width and height of the canvas, like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Y8rx.png)

I try set Responsive but width or height  is always one that is the top grid

Comment: You needs to provide minimal reproduce code, please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the padding option to add space between the edge of the canvas and the chart by setting `options.layout.padding`

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/general/padding.html

Answer (score 1):

the problem has been resolved, just set the padding

Layout:{

Padding:{

Top: 130

}

},
If you want to set the width and height, remember to set the response: true,